# Docker compose volumes Nuxtjs

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, containers, nuxt.js

i am trying to dockerize Nuxt js app and nest js in the backend

I want it now for development

i have 2 folders, eva-frontend and eva-backend

I get them up and runnig on docker but when i want to change something in the frontend code, docker doesn't detect it. In backend it works, so i guess that there is something wrong with my volume

The other problem is when i go to my application i login and when i refresh the page i should login again

locally on my pc i don't have this problem, only on docker
so i guess there is something wrong with my Volume in the front end
dockerfile backend:

```
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"]
```

dockerfile frontend:

```
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY package.json ./
COPY . .

RUN npm install


EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./eva-frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./eva-frontend:/app
  backend:
    build: ./eva-backend
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./eva-backend:/app
```

Comment: You are sharing the data in the wrong way. Read about volumes.

Comment: @RichardRublev Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?  i followed many articles and they are doing it like that

Comment: Use docker inspect output to check you mounted volumes. They should point to the same directory.

Comment: @RichardRublev so what should i change in my file?

Comment: Read this https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Can you use Node directly, without Docker, for ordinary development?  You could `docker-compose up -d backend` to run the backend in Docker while you work on the frontend using standard host-based tools.  (And then I'd recommend deleting those `volumes:` blocks entirely.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes locally everything works fine, but i would like to dockerize my whole app. and i need volumes for het reload. when i change something in my code then it's changed in docker without building it again